# Send mail using python and html

Tags: python, html, mysql, email

I am trying to obtain a result set from SQL query and add it to my email template which is an HTML file.

### Two Functions:

One for mail summary and the other one to change the email body.

I am using smtplib and email packages from python to send out a mail.

```
#send a email

from fileOps import fileOps
from dbOps import dbOps
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP, SMTPException
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

mailFrom = ''
password = ''
mailTo = ''
mailServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587
s = smtplib.SMTP(mailServer,port)

#function for email summary 
def emailSummary():
    try:
        #security
        s.starttls()
        s.login(mailFrom,password)

        #for fetching all the records
        dbObj = dbOps()
        db = dbObj.connectDB()
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CASE_MASTER.AGREEMENTID, CASE_MASTER.NO_OF_FILES FROM " \
              "CASE_MASTER LEFT JOIN CASE_FILE_STATUS ON CASE_FILE_STATUS.MOVED_TO_AWS_FLAG = CASE_MASTER.MOVED_TO_AWS_FLAG " \
              "AND CASE_FILE_STATUS.MOVED_TO_AWS_Date AND CASE_MASTER.MOVED_TO_AWS_FLAG IS NOT NULL " \
              "WHERE CASE_FILE_STATUS.MOVED_TO_AWS_FLAG = 1 AND CASE_FILE_STATUS.MOVED_TO_AWS_Date IS NOT NULL"
        resultSet = dbObj.readData(db, sql)

        getEmailBody(resultSet)

        emailBody = getEmailBody(resultSet)
        s.sendmail(mailFrom, mailTo,emailBody)
        s.quit()
 #       print("Email Successfully sent !!! ")
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e :
        print(e)

#function to get emailBody 
def getEmailBody(resultSet):
    try:
        htmlTemplate = open('summaryTemplate.html', 'r')
        alert_msg = MIMEText(htmlTemplate.read(), "html", "utf-8")
        html = htmlTemplate.read()
        part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        part2 = """<table>
                    % for r in resultSet:
                        <tr>
                            % for cell in r:
                                <td>${cell}</td>
                        % endfor</tr>
                    % endfor</table>""".format(**locals())

        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "HERO_FC_DM_DB"
        msg['From'] = mailFrom
        msg['To'] = mailTo
        msg.attach(part1)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

emailSummary()
```

I am getting the row but not getting the content from that row

`['81173'] 'cell'`

```
 File "C:\Users\sailee.pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 858, in sendmail
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
'cell'
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I am getting the above error
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 68, in  emailSummary()
line 37, in emailSummary
s.sendmail(mailFrom, mailTo,emailBody)
line 858, in sendmail esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
'cell'
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
expected  o/p :
['81173']
'file1.jpg'
'file2.txt'
```

Comment: You have some formatting issues in your question, the very first part where you begin, " I am trying to obtain", should not be in code text. It also looks like your second paragraph contains code that was not formatted correctly. Fixing these issues may help others understand and answer your question easier.

Comment: @sailee I have made some edits to the question, please post the detailed error in the question or comments

Comment: One possible cause is the async behavior of the SQL query. Any of the database queries being asynchronous, you have to write the code that needs to be executed based on the results of the query should be in a callback function.

Comment: @tsumit the sql query which you are saying is solved but still it says the same.

Comment: `getEmailBody` doesn't return anything.  It should probably return `msg`.

Comment: lets close this question as it is solved. thank you all